# Is it possible to disable _FILE_OFFSET_BITS==64 in CPython (as a Yocto/Poky package)?

Tags: python, yocto, cpython

I have a bitbake recipe with a dependency on Python2.7.

I'm trying to compile a C file (generated by CFFI) that includes both `Python.h` and a library header that includes `fts.h` somewhere down the line. It fails with

`#error "<fts.h> cannot be used with -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS==64"`

I noticed that `_FILE_OFFSET_BITS` is set to `64` in `pyconfig.h:1136`, and that file is automatically generated, so I'm wondering if I can prevent this `#define` from being included, at the cost of not being able to access files >2GB.

For the record, Python is being included through

`RDEPENDS_${PN} += "python"`

in the file

`/common/recipes-core/packagegroups/nativesdk-packagegroup-swi-toolchain.bb`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh it ended up being rather simple!

files/disable-lfs.patch

```
--- Python-2.7.3.orig/configure.in
+++ Python-2.7.3/configure.in
@@ -1449,7 +1449,7 @@
 # structures (such as rlimit64) without declaring them. As a
 # work-around, disable LFS on such configurations

-use_lfs=yes
+use_lfs=no
 AC_MSG_CHECKING(Solaris LFS bug)
 AC_COMPILE_IFELSE([AC_LANG_PROGRAM([[
 #define _LARGEFILE_SOURCE 1
```

python-native_%.bbappend

```
FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend := "${THISDIR}/files:"
SRC_URI += "file://disable-lfs.patch"
```

Comment: I apply your fix on configure.ac for Python-3.6.2 and call autoconf. Thanks for posting the solution.